# JavaFX Dynamically add Nodes to pane with fx:id or id

Tags: javafx, fxml

I can create Nodes on a pane with a for next loop, but do not have the ability 
to assign these nodes a fx:id or a id
Is this possible number one? If so what do I need to add to my code?
Or do I have the option to write the information to a FXML file with the for next loop?

```
    private void MakeNode(){
    for (int A = 1; A <= 42; A++){
    if(A==1){
        X=40;
        Y=40;
    }else if(A>1 && A<=7){
        X = X + 120;
        Y = 40;
    }else if(A==8){
        X = 40;
        Y = 160;
    }else if(A>8&& A<=14){
        X = X + 120;
        Y = 160;
    }else if(A==15){
        X = 40;
        Y = 280;
    }else if(A>15&& A<=21){
        X = X + 120;
        Y = 280;
    }else if(A==22){
        X = 40;
        Y = 400;
    }else if(A>22&& A<=28){
        X = X + 120;
        Y = 400;
    }else if(A==29){
        X = 40;
        Y = 520;
    }else if(A>29&& A<=35){
        X = X + 120;
        Y = 520;
    }else if(A==36){
        X = 40;
        Y = 640;
    }else if(A>36&& A<=42){
        X = X + 120;
        Y = 640;
    }
        cirA = new Circle(X,Y,16);
        //fxid = cir.concat(String.valueOf(A));
        //fxid = cir+String.valueOf(A);
        //cirA.setId(fxid);
        cirA.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
        cirA.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        cirA.setStrokeWidth(4.0);
        pane.getChildren().add(cirA);

    }
}
```

Comment: The `fx:id` is *only* used to make nodes that are defined in FXML available in Java code in your controller. Since your circle is already defined in Java, your question doesn't really make sense. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: As an aside, instead of that great big `if`-`else` construct, do: `int column = (A-1) % 7;` `int row = (A-1)/7;` `X = 40 +120 *column;` `Y = 40 + 120 * row;`.

Comment: @James_D I am trying to create nodes then manipulate the nodes. Example if end user clicks on the Circle a line is drawn Horz from one circle to the adjacent circle. I got lazy and was tired of creating one node at a time. With out the fx:id it is hard to apply program logic to the nodes.

Comment: Creating them in a loop like this is the correct way. But setting an `fx:id` simply makes no sense if there is no FXML (or if the circles are not defined in FXML). What is stopping you doing what you want to do with the code you have?

Comment: @James_D I do have an fxml file with this project. I have discovered that the nodes have an index number. and X and Y values but this makes management of the nodes less than satisfactory. I have tried the css id to manage the nodes but quite cumbersome. As I said I got lazy making Nodes one at a time thanks for the help

Comment: Yes, I understand other things may be defined in FXML, but the circles are defined in Java (presumably already in the controller). The `fx:id` is ***only*** a mechanism for accessing nodes defined in FXML in your controller. You don't need that here: the circles are ***already*** defined in your controller. A CSS id is not for "managing" nodes; it is just an id that can be matched by an external stylesheet. Just register the handlers you need with the circles directly in the Java code. I still don't really understand what you are asking, I guess.

Comment: @James_D What I am asking is once I click on say circle number one how do I know that it is circle number one and not circle number 42. I need a handler for each circle and with out some property it seems impossible. This is a game called Dots & Boxes where when you make a Box out of the 4 dots you get a point. I have written it with each circle having a fx:id and it functions can you include a link to your github page please I liked the code you used to create the circle thanks

Comment: Just register a handler with each circle in the loop...

Comment: I won't be back at my computer for a while but if no one else has posted an example by then I'll post one.

Answer (score 2):

`fx:id` is just a mechanism for getting a reference to elements defined in FXML to the controller. If you are defining nodes in the controller anyway, there is no need for (or indeed, no way to use) `fx:id` at all.

You already have a reference to the `Circle` when you create it. So just do whatever you need right there. Here's a simple example (I cleaned your code up to make it much less verbose):

```
private void makeNode() {
    for (int circleIndex = 0 ; circleIndex < 42 ; circleIndex++) {
        int column = circleIndex % 7 ;
        int row = circleIndex / 7 ;
        double x = 40 + 120 * column ;
        double y = 40 + 120 * row ;
        Circle circle = new Circle(x, y, 16);
        circle.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
        circle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        circle.setStrokeWidth(4.0);
        pane.getChildren().add(circle);

        circle.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            System.out.println("Clicked on ["+column+", "+row+"]");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the code. I will try to write less verbose code